# Верное ценообразование в интернет магазине

Tags: php, mysql

Привет, коллеги! Имею вопрос по ценообразованию в интернет магазине, и не могу прийти к какому-либо относительно верному решению.

Имеется интернет магазин, для примера это будут игрушки.
У интернет магазина много поставщиков, позиции пересекаются, то есть один и тот же товар может быть у пяти поставщиков одновременно, но цены и наличие различаются.

Допустим, есть игрушечная машинка. Она в наличии у двух поставщиков, а у каждого из поставщиков по склада. Если бы цены были приблизительно одинаковы для всех товарных позиций, это было бы идеально, но кризис с валютой в нашей Раше и спрос на те или иные товары делают свое черное дело.

[image: Изображение]

Случается так, что на некоторых складах цена существенно отличается от всех остальных цен. Полагаю, дело в том что товар старый, закупленный до 2014 года, цена на него в два раза ниже.

Изначально выставлял цены по методу

```
$data = array(
    array('price'=>2005, 'amount' => 2),
    array('price'=>2006, 'amount' => 4),
    array('price'=>2007, 'amount' => 8),
    array('price'=>2007, 'amount' => 8),
    array('price'=>2007, 'amount' => 4),
    array('price'=>2007, 'amount' => 16)
);

foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $price[$key]  = $row['price'];
    $amount[$key] = $row['amount'];
}

array_multisort($price, SORT_ASC, $amount, SORT_DESC, $data);
```

Брал первое значение массива $data и выводил на сайт цену = 2005 и наличие = 2. Мне этот метод не кажется корректным, потому что работает он только при сравнительно одинаковых ценах и наличии по складам. Соль на рану теперь сыпят еще и ситуации, когда имеем на 10 складах цену, допустим в 3000 рублей, еще на 10 складах цену 3500 рублей, а всего на одном складе цену в 1500 рублей и низкое количество товара в наличии.
А по моим старым формулам (когда поставщиков была всего пара) на сайт выводилась именно минимальная цена с максимальным количеством товара. В описанном на php примере на сайте появится цена 2005 рублей с наличием в 2 шт, а по данным на картинке - машинка за 1500 рублей. Это в корне неверно, поэтому теперь ищу новые пути для оптимизации ценообразования.

**Собственно, сам вопрос**: как выбрать оптимальную цену в автоматическом режиме? Ручная обработка отпадает, потому что позиций более ста тысяч.

Работаю с php/mysql
В БД по товарам имею 4 таблицы: products, suppliers, warehouses, prices.

```
- products (список товаров, 50к позиций)
- suppliers (поставщики, id/название/телефоны, 10 штук)
- warehouses (список складов, каждый склад привязан к поставщику, по 5 складов на поставщика)
- prices (цены и наличие по каждому товару, каждого поставщика на каждом складе)
```

Описал структуру для общего понимания, что на один товар может приходится до 50 записей в таблице с ценами и наличием.

Подскажите, куда двигаться x_x

Спасибо!

Comment: Может стоит показывать цену в виде `от ... до ...`?

Comment: Яндекс.маркет такую фишку не пропустит

Comment: Высчитать среднюю арифметическую и указать все количество товара?

Comment: Как один из вариантов решения проблемы - да.

Comment: Тогда делайте запрос с нужной вам группировкой по товарам и двумя вычисляемыми полями: суммой по полю количество, суммой по полю (цена * количество). Средняя цена получится как деление второго поля на первое.

Comment: Существует еще такой ньюанс, как минимальная розничная цена, на некоторых товарах. То есть игрушка в закупке 3000 рублей, в продаже 3500 и ни рублем ниже. А по старому курсу она 1500 рублей и 1800 в продаже. Если усреднять - мы получим цену ниже новой МРЦ в 3500 рублей и нам наваляют :) Но понять где какая МРЦ в автоматическом режиме - сложно.